# Do we need backend framework if user React or Angular

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, frontend, backend

So question is do we need backend framework e.g. Laverel etc. if we user Angular\React? Don't undestend why we need cuz i use baclend only for REST API, I can not understand why they can be useful if we do all job on froendend

Comment: Your question is fairly broad and very opinionated, it's not a good fit for this site at all.  Also, the answer varies broadly depending on your definition of a "backend framework" and also varies depending on what your project is attempting to accomplish.  In *very broad terms*, you probably don't need both a frontend framework and a backend framework that both generate HTML from templates, if that's what you are trying to ask....

Answer (score 2):

The need for server side code is largely independent from the use of client side code.

Many projects require server side and client side code in order to function at all (e.g. if data needs to be shared between users of a site). Even those that don't usually *should* involve server side code [as a best practise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Given a project where server side code is needed, there is never a *need* for a framework. A framework is a tool that can (in some circumstances) make the development of code easier, but can always be replaced with from scratch code. A developer should select the most appropriate tool for the job.